# How to write a function to read elements from 2D array?

Tags: java, function

When I run the code in the stdin line the program gives me an exception. How to solve it so the program works?

```
static double read_matrix(double matrix[][]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Enter elements:");
            matrix[i][j]=stdin.nextInt();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exception? And how are you calling the method? And what inputs are you feeding it?

Comment: This exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
I am trying to enter elements in 2D array with function

Comment: @FancyPantsGeneral exceptions are thrown at a line. Which line is that exception thrown at? (please don't just tell the number, make it clear which line it is) And please [edit] your question to include the stack trace.

Comment: @FancyPantsGeneral where the heck does stdin is declared, you are using a "stdin" variable but is never declared.

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring `stdin` inside your method.

To read from the user-input you can use for example: `Scanner(System.in)` that is provided by `java.util`.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main.read_matrix(new double[2][2]);
  }

  static double read_matrix(double matrix[][]) {
    int i, j;
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Enter element:");
            matrix[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    scanner.close(); // make sure to close it to prevent memory leaks
    return 0;
  }
}
```